# 2018: a year in moderation

Tags: discussion, moderation, statistics

It's New Year's Day in [Stack Exchange land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zulu_Time)...

A distinguishing characteristic of these sites is how they are moderated:

> We designed the Stack Exchange network engine to be mostly self-regulating, in that we amortize the overall moderation cost of the system across thousands of teeny-tiny slices of effort contributed by regular, everyday users.
> -- [A Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)

While there certainly are [Moderators](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/11/21/our-theory-of-moderation-re-visited/) here, a significant amount of the *moderation* is done by ordinary people, using the privileges
they've earned by virtue of their contributions to the site. Each of you contributes a little bit of time and effort, and together you accomplish much.

As we enter a new year, let's pause and reflect, taking a moment to appreciate the work that we do here together.
To that end, here is how the moderation done here on Academia breaks down by activity over the past 12 months:

```
                 Action                  Moderators Community¹
---------------------------------------- ---------- ----------
Users suspended²                                 24         30
Users destroyed                                 264          0
Users deleted                                    13          0
Users contacted                                  48          0
User banned from review                           2          0
Tasks reviewed³: Suggested Edit queue            49      2,528
Tasks reviewed³: Reopen Vote queue                8      1,323
Tasks reviewed³: Low Quality Posts queue         21      2,175
Tasks reviewed³: Late Answer queue                3        568
Tasks reviewed³: First Post queue                15      4,946
Tasks reviewed³: Close Votes queue               74      8,595
Tags merged                                      37          0
Tag synonyms proposed                            16          0
Tag synonyms created                             15          0
Revisions redacted                               27          0
Questions unprotected                             1          0
Questions reopened                               59         54
Questions protected                              82        265
Questions migrated                               45          4
Questions flagged⁴                               57      2,847
Questions closed                                489      1,966
Question flags handled⁴                         829      2,075
Posts unlocked                                   13         18
Posts undeleted                                  27         74
Posts locked                                     24        341
Posts deleted⁵                                  499      2,350
Posts bumped                                      0        366
Escalations to the CM team                       19          0
Comments undeleted                              267          0
Comments flagged                                 32      2,926
Comments deleted⁶                             7,410      3,678
Comment flags handled                         2,244        714
Answers flagged                                 135      2,946
Answer flags handled                          1,905      1,176
All comments on a post moved to chat            208          0
```

#### Footnotes

¹ "Community" here refers both to [the membership of Academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users) *without* [diamonds next to their names](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators), and to the automated systems otherwise known as [user #-1](https://academia.stackexchange.com/users/-1).

² The system will suspend users under three circumstances: when a user is recreated after being previously suspended, when a user is recreated after being destroyed for spam or abuse, and when a network-wide suspension is in effect on an account.

³ This counts every review that was submitted (not skipped) - so the 3 suggested edits reviews needed to approve an edit would count as 3, the goal being to indicate the frequency of moderation actions. This also applies to flags, etc.

⁴ Includes close flags (but *not* close or reopen votes).

⁵ This ignores numerous deletions that happen automatically in response to some other action.

⁶ This includes comments deleted by their own authors (which also account for some number of handled comment flags).

Wishing you all a happy new year...

Answer (score 3):

Interesting! As a moderator, I didn't realize that over half of the flags are being handled by non-diamond users. Thank you all!

Comment: I am guessing a bunch of those are the community bot handling spam and rude/abusive flags, but it does mean that as quickly as we generally handle flags, there are times that our users are getting the job done by raising enough flags.

Comment: @StrongBad: Also remember that NAA, VLQ, closure, and even comment flags can be handled by the community at times.

Comment: I'm assuming that if a flag is raised to, for example, close a question, if close votes close the question before a diamond gets to the flag it would mark it as community handled. Academia seems to do much better on that than any of the other smaller communities I'm part of, so I think it's probably more than just the bot.