# Would you be interested in becoming a moderator?

Tags: discussion

We're thinking of running a moderator election. The moderation workload for this site is not too burdensome, but having one more moderator on the team would allow a better redistribution of the workload when someone has work peaks at the office.

Since there is no urgency, before starting an election, we would like to gauge the community to see if there is a reasonable number of potential candidates to ensure competitiveness. In case, the election will likely take place around fall 2021.

So, if you're interested in becoming a moderator, you're welcome to express your interest and motivation here! Indeed, expressing interest now is not committing and, likewise, not expressing it now doesn't keep you from running if there is an election.

[This Q&A](https://academia.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4534) covers many aspects of the moderator activity, but if you have further questions, please don't hesitate to ask here.

Comment: Agree that an additional mod would be helpful, though mod functions seem to be handled in a timely manner. No interest myself, but there are a few active users I'd recommend for the quality of their contributions generally.

Comment: By the way, the Fall date may be fungible: if you are interested but are worried about the timing (election near the beginning of Fall semester), please let us know that as well.

Comment: _a better redistribution of the workload when someone has work peaks at the office_ What's the time in the day you guys need coverage? North American? Europe? Or in between?

Comment: @scaaahu: It’s not really a timezone thing. Most of the workload is semi-urgent things that take a rather long time to handle.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft I got it. Like some difficult Meta questions that would take quite sometime to answer. In that case, I take my name off the list.

Comment: @scaaahu: Meta activity is in that category, but it’s not the major part. The major part would be too-many-comments flags and deciding about the fate of consistently rude users.

Comment: I suggest simply spending less time on the too-many-comments flags.

Comment: Is this dead now? It's been very quiet for a while. No hordes massed at the gates.

Comment: @Buffy: Kind of. [A decision was made.](https://academia.stackexchange.com/election/4)

Answer (score 18):

I think the team here does a great job of covering things and it's rare that anything lingers that shouldn't linger, but I trust y'all if you want an extra pair of hands to cover.

I'd probably put my name in the hat if there were an election.

Comment: And I would probably support you. I note you are already a mod on another site. I'll also note that your posts and such are helpful and not just in the technical sense.

Comment: @Buffy Thanks; yes, I moderate on Biology where the work load is even less than here (both from popularity and the nature of the sites). I think we have a lot of users who would be well-qualified to moderate the site, should they choose to do so.

Comment: And, I won't even complain about you beating me to the punch: e.g. https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/170849/75368

Comment: I hope that you don't.

Comment: @user1271772 I'm sorry you feel that way, but respect your opinion. I know we've had some interactions across the network (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366736/who-can-change-usernames-and-when-would-they-do-it-if-theres-no-flag-or-imperso is the last I recall); I thought these have been cordial but perhaps I am mistaken. If you can elaborate, it might help me improve for the future, but I also understand if you'd rather not restart some past argument.

Comment: I certainly hope to see your self nomination happen.

Comment: It would take me a long time and a lot of effort to compile a list of all the nasty back-and-forth exchanges you've had with people like Franck, so I don't want to have to do it if not necessary, but I can do it if you do nominate yourself and if I have time. That link you provided here was to quite a cordial exchange with *myself* in which I asked you to convert your comment to an answer, and you did, and I clicked "accept" right away, so that's not what I was talking about here!

Comment: @user1271772 Understood, thank you. I'd prefer not to discuss other individuals with a third party, but of course you're welcome to raise any specific concerns you have with what is public on the site.

Comment: @BryanKrause In response to your previous comment where you asked for elaboration, I can do it if you think it could help you improve for the future (as you said in the comment), but I don't think there's any need for a rush to do it during the election. Also, with only one other candidate, who also happens to have a much lower candidate score and overall rep than you, it looks like you're on your way to winning the election anyway --- so congratulations in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Although I think that there are some excellent potential candidates for the moderator position, with far more reputation on the website than me, I would be happy to help.